# React Native : Background Image not being shown in first load

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

For first load my application **BackgroundImage** not being shown in **First load**.

Truly, I'm using a map and these are backgroungs for clusters

```
componentWillMount(){
    if (this.props.pointCount < 10) {
        this.cluster_image = require('../assets/cluster1_mobile.png') ;
    }else if (this.props.pointCount < 100) {
        this.cluster_image = require('../assets/cluster2_mobile.png') ;
    }else{
        this.cluster_image = require('../assets/cluster3_mobile.png') ;
    }
}
```

And in Render

```
<ImageBackground source={ this.cluster_image }>
   <Text>
      {this.props.pointCount}
   </Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you need setup in a `constructor`

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
if (props.pointCount < 10) {
        this.cluster_image = require('../assets/cluster1_mobile.png') ;
    }else if (props.pointCount < 100) {
        this.cluster_image = require('../assets/cluster2_mobile.png') ;
    }else{
        this.cluster_image = require('../assets/cluster3_mobile.png') ;
    }
}
```